# Passing a value in inline PHP to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables, inline

```
var testvr = <?php echo 5;?>;
```

When this is used in my javascript I get an "Unexpected token <" error on the line. I've seen countless examples of people setting a javascript variable like this so I'm a bit confused. I've seen some do it as

```
var testvr = "<?php echo 5;?>";
```

But that passes the code as a string to the variable. I'm really just looking for a way to simply set a javascript variable to something from php, nothing fancy at all it would just be a number such as 5.

Comment: Show some more code. And of course you have to call it from PHP script.

Comment: pass the code as a string to the variable and then parse it as int in javascript

Comment: There is no problem with the code provided there must some different error. you can share more code

Comment: Is this code in a .js or a .php file?

Comment: The problem was that it wasn't a .php file, been so long since I've used inline PHP I forgot that bit. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When this is used in my javascript I get an "Unexpected token `<`" error on the line.

This means that you aren't passing the file through a PHP parser before delivering it to the browser.

Presumably you are placing the PHP in a `.js` file. Either rename that file to `.php` or configure your server to process your `.js` files with PHP.

Don't forget that PHP will default to sending `Content-Type: text/html` so make sure you include `header("Content-Type: application/javascript");`.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to use an object:

```
<?php
   $vars = array('var1' => 'val1', 'var2' => 'val2', 'intvar' => 55);
?>

<script>
   var myvars = <?php json_encode($vars);?>
   console.log(myvars.var1);
   console.log(myvars.var2);
   console.log(myvars.intvar);
</script>
```

The above will keep numbers as numbers and all unsafe characters will get escaped.